# Is there a limit on the number of characters that you can save from a gmail contextual gadget to an external database?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I am in the process of writing a gmail contextual gadget that hooks into gmail
to connect it with an external application. I have hit a problem: if the
incoming email seems to exceed about 1000 characters, then I seem unable to
save a full copy of that email directly to the external app database (there
is not problem to save email content that is less than about 1000
characters). Could someone confirm that this is indeed a limitation imposed by
Gmail and if so, is there any way to circumvent this limitation?

Comment: In the past, I have successfully been able to read beyond 1000 characters from Gmail. Can you please post some code so that we know something else is not wrong

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a custom extractor for the gadget.    
I then retrieve the values in the Gadget spec using google.contentmatch.getContentMatches(), after having added
<Require feature="google.contentmatch">
      <Param name="extractors">
        <ID>:extractorID
      </Param>
</Require>

in the Gadget too.

All the other values that I read with google.contentmatch.getContentMatches() are correct, just the email body is truncated to 1000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a 1000 character limit on the data that can be extracted. See the [limitations](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/contextual_gadgets#limitations) section which states "An extractor can return a maximum of 1,000 characters in each of its output fields".

Also, the [troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/contextual_gadgets#troubleshooting) sections says "The extracted match must be no more than 1000 characters"

Comment: IMO, the extractor only triggers the appearance of the gadget and a custom extractor will not help you overcome the 1000 chars limitation.

Comment: You're correct in that the doc now states you cannot overcome the limitation. I'm not sure what if anything has changed but I have updated my answer.